# Inserting similar strings in a page in to the database at once

Tags: mysql, database, string

I want to insert similar strings in a page in to the database at once! for example, I want to insert each line in to a table row:

```
$flag = 'AD.png'; $title = 'Andorra';
$flag = 'AE.png'; $title = 'United Arab Emirates';
$flag = 'AF.png'; $title = 'Afghanistan';
$flag = 'AG.png'; $title = 'Antigua and Barbuda';
$flag = 'AI.png'; $title = 'Anguilla';
$flag = 'AL.png'; $title = 'Albania';
$flag = 'AM.png'; $title = 'Armenia';
$flag = 'AN.png'; $title = 'Netherlands Antilles';
```

My database rows are:

```
`flag_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`flag_Title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`flag_ImageId` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`flag_Id`)
```

How should I do that?!

Comment: What do you mean "at once"?

Comment: @ironcito, I meant all them together as Bart Friederichs answered below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) multiple records in one query:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (flag_ImageId, flag_Title) VALUES
('AD.png', 'Andorra'),
('AI.png', 'Anguilla),
...
('US.png', 'USA');
```

Comment: Swap the fields, I would think.

Answer (score 0):

this foreach item:

`insert into tablename flag_Title, flag_ImageId values ('AD.png', 'Andorra');`

If you want to do it in 1 transaction add START TRANSACTION; and COMMIT; like:

```
START TRANSACTION;
insert into tablename flag_Title, flag_ImageId values ('AD.png', 'Andorra');
insert into tablename flag_Title, flag_ImageId values ('AD.png', 'Andorra');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: updated answer, this is as close you get to doing it all at once

Comment: @BartFriederichs Until now I thought your way was the same as separate queries, but I was wrong. When 1 of the values can't be added none of the records will be inserted. I like your example more as you have less characters to type. +1 for you.